# How to execute a mongo command in sh file?

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I have a file named db.sh in bin folder and when I try to execute this command `$ sh bin/db.sh` I receive `bin/db.sh: line 2: mongod:` command not found in console what is wrong there?

```
#!/bin/sh
mongod --dbpath db --rest --jsonp;
```

Comment: what's the output of `which mongod`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean what I try to do is to start this cms https://github.com/jonniespratley/angular-cms

Comment: run that command in your terminal, and post the output.

Comment: `bin/db.sh: line 2: mongod: command not found`

Comment: I meant, run `which mongod` in your terminal, and post the output of it.

Comment: I don't have any output on this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78926/discussion-between-n9code-and-flap-jack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the situation:

`which mongod` would give you the path to the `mongod` binary. If there is no output from `which`, there which could not find `mongod`. This may be the case that there is not path in the `$PATH` variable, that contains the `mongod` binary. You can make sure by executing `echo $PATH`.

If you have your MongoDB installed manually, in some directory, then you will need to add `/path/to/your/mongodb/bin` to the `$PATH` variable in your `.bashrc`, like this:

```
PATH=/path/to/your/mongodb/bin:$PATH
```

But anyway :) seems like you do not have MongoDB installed on your machine. Follow [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) to install it.